# Where does TeamCity get the value for %system.teamcity.build.workingDir%

Tags: parameters, continuous-integration, command, teamcity

We have TeamCity and on the `[Runner: Command Line]` of the `[Build Configuration]` page, there is a `[Command Parameter]` field `%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%`

My question is where does TeamCity get this value from as when i look at the System Properties of the Agent i do not see it has been set. 
`%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%` does not appear in the list of `[System Properties]` or `[Environment Variables]`

Answer (score 36):

Where are you looking? It is listed along with other system properties:

[image]

@Snahider - a build at any point runs only on one agent. So `%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%` will be set to the current build's working dir. It is not same as `%system.agent.work.dir%` which is the parent of the checkout directory for each build.

For example if you have your agent installed in `C:\BuildAgent` the `%system.agent.work.dir%` will be `C:\BuildAgent\work` whereas `%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%` will be something like `C:\BuildAgent\work\8b0fde2bf2d2efc0` if you have not specified the checkout directory in VCS settings or if you have set it, to say `wd` it will be `C:\BuildAgent\work\wd`

One more thing is that, if in the build step step you change the working directory, to say `Examples`, `%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%` will, as the name suggests, point to that - `C:\BuildAgent\work\wd\Examples` So `%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%` can change depending on what is happening, while `%system.agent.work.dir%` will remain same for an agent. Hope this explains the difference.

Comment: Where do you get the listing of system properties?

Comment: @user3174075, I think that [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Predefined+Build+Parameters).

Answer (score 3):

**%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%** documentation says:

> The build working directory is the directory set as current for the build process. By default, this is the same directory as the Build Checkout Directory.
>   If the build script needs to run from a location other than the checkout directory, then you can specify it explicitly using the Working Directory field on the settings page of the build runner.

If you have the WebServer and only on Agent in the same machine that directory is the same as the **%system.agent.work.dir%**

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Agent+Work+Directory

In my windows box is **C:/Users/[user]/.BuildAgent/work**.

if you have multiple agents i dont know what will be the directory. I recommend you to use %system.agent.work.dir% instead of %system.teamcity.build.workingDir%.

You can test the value of any variable using the same "command line build": write the variable in the "Command Parameters" input and run the build, you can see the real value in the logs when the build finshed.

Comment: you quote the documentation, which says so many things, but still venture to say `%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%` and `%system.agent.work.dir%` are same!

Comment: @manojlds - You are right. My comment was based on the case of a default installation. Also i forgot to include the temp directory. The correct sentence should be: %system.teamcity.build.workingDir% = %system.agent.work.dir%/[tempdir] (for a default installation).

Comment: again, not true. Depends on what the checkout directory is and if the working directory for the build step is set or not. Default installation doesn't mean default configuration of the build.